# Python Inheritance:Attribute error when using a parent method to print out a inherited variable

Tags: python, inheritance

1. I am new to python inheritance, and I met a simple issue just to
   print out variables.
2. I have a parent class prints

```
class prints:
   def __init__(self):
       self.__name = ""
   def getName(self):
       return self.__name

class A(prints):
   def __init__(self):
       self.__name = "A"

a = A()
n = a.getName()

print(n)
```

I got an error

```
 AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '_prints__name'
```

- I know I can do it in C++, but I am scratching my head to figure out
  where is wrong in my python code..

> Could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't implement private variables but it does help reduce the risk of name clashes with variables you'd like to keep private to a class. If your instance variable starts with two underscores, python will prepend the class name. See "name mangling" in [Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)  So, the `prints` `__name` variable is renamed `_prints__name`.

This method works, except when it doesn't. Inherited classes don't have a natural way to get to the variable. Generally this isn't a problem because it is class private after all. One way to use it is to call methods in the base class. In this case, you likely should have called the base class `__init__` to set the variable. But if you want to use it directly, you can do `self._prints__name`.

```
class prints:
   def __init__(self):
       self.__name = ""
   def getName(self):
       return self.__name

class A(prints):
   def __init__(self):
       self._prints__name = "A"

a = A()
n = a.getName()

print(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I wrote it that way for parent being a virtual class, just a common ood practice. So I should make all vars public in parent class in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a variable with prefix `__`. 
Officially python does not have private variables, but when you use a var with prefix `__`, the it stored as `_className__var`,

If you peek inside `a.__dict__`:

```
a.__dict__
Out[9]: {'_A__name': 'A'}
```

So, when you do `a.getName()`, inheritance logic that you would expect kicks in 
that searches parent for `getName` by looking at `prints.__dict__`(which finds a match)

This would attempt to resolve `__name` of the parent, except in this case it would be looking to resolve it as `_prints__name` of `self` which is an instance of `A`.

This is called name mangling

Comment: thank you for answering. I have picked an answer but appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
class prints:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = ""

   def getName(self):
       return self.name

class A(prints):
   def __init__(self):
       self.name = "A"

 a = A()
 n = a.getName()

print(n)
```

refer to basics in python https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp